# How to see changes in a postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, database-backups

My postresql database is updated each night.

At the end of each nightly update, I need to know what data changed.

The update process is complex, taking a couple of hours and requires dozens of scripts, so I don't know if that influences how I could see what data has changed.

The database is around 1 TB in size, so any method that requires starting a temporary database may be very slow.

The database is an AWS instance (RDS). I have automated backups enabled (these are [different to RDS snapshots which are user initiated](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/)). Is it possible to see the difference between two RDS automated backups?

Comment: You could use something like https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json (or https://github.com/leptonix/decoding-json) to "log" the changes done through the day.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it is possible to see difference between RDS snapshots. But in the past we tested several solutions for similar problem. Maybe you can take some inspiration from it.

1. Obvious solution is of course auditing system. This way you can see in relatively simply way what was changed. Depending on granularity of your auditing system down to column values. Of course there is impact on your application due auditing triggers and queries into audit tables.
2. Another possibility is - for tables with primary keys you can store values of primary key and  'xmin' and 'ctid' hidden system columns (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html) for each row before updated and compare them with values after update. But this way you can identify only changed / inserted / deleted rows but not changes in different columns.
3. You can make streaming replica and set replication slots (and to be on the safe side also WAL log archiving ). Then stop replication on replica before updates and compare data after updates using dblink selects. But these queries can be very heavy.